# Example of non-simple Banach algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis

i ask for an example of non-simple Banach algebra.
non-simple means that the intersection of all maximal ideals is not zero.

Comment: For commutative rings, more common terms for "the intersection of maximal ideals is zero" include *semiprimitive* and *Jacobson semisimple*.  But I understand that you could have come by your term from functional analysis literature, which sometimes uses terms differently from the main body of ring theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B$ be the space of upper  triangular $2\times 2$ matrices (with the operator norm). Consider $x=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$. If $\lambda\ne0$ then $x-\lambda I$ is invertible; hence $x$ lies in every maximal ideal.